# How can I install Braintree on a Heroku Ruby server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, heroku, braintree

I am very new to Heroku and I don't have experience with ruby. I am trying to make my online server generate a token for my mobile client. I have also a created a Sandbox account. I am following the the tutorial in the below link: 
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/ruby

Keep in mind I'm new to this and I have no idea what I should do. In the below picture, is says add the following code to my project. What project? Where is this project? And how can I upload it to Heroku after I added the below code?

[image]

Can someone explain or send me a link to dummy it down for me (a lot) so I can understand how I can install Braintree on Swift using Heroku? Possibly a with images so I can understand better. I also need to know how I can tell my Xcode app to send tokens to my Heroku server to process them. I have been stuck on this task for a few weeks now and I still don't have any idea what I'm doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to only add the gem to your gemfile locally. When you commit to heroku it will install the gem on the server by itself
Braintree has decent documentation on how to add the gem.

Those variables go in your environment.rb

Documentation: https://github.com/lyang/braintree-rails/wiki

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already deployed Braintree to Heroku using the link below: 
github.com/braintree/braintree_express_example
I am still not sure what to do after. Could you please expand your answer? Or could you possibly provide a link to the documentation you mentioned?

Comment: I will link the docs once i am on my system. What is the problem you are having,  errors, log etc after you deploy to heroku. Also why do you need to deploy to heroku if you need it in your ios app.braintree has a drop-in functionality for apps. You dont need a server